# Spring EL File.renameTo is not working on mounted directories

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-el

I have this bean working perfectly on linux and windows, but not moving files when the source is on a mounted file system (e.g. a network drive). I know that File.renameTo is not capable to do such move instead copy and delete should be done, but within a SpelExpression, how? I've also tried registering a custom method, but it did not work. Any suggestions?

```
@Bean
TransactionSynchronizationFactory transactionSynchronizationFactory() {
    ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
    ExpressionEvaluatingTransactionSynchronizationProcessor syncProcessor = new ExpressionEvaluatingTransactionSynchronizationProcessor();
    syncProcessor.setBeanFactory(applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory());
    syncProcessor.setAfterCommitExpression(parser.parseExpression(
            "payload.renameTo(new java.io.File(@inboundProcessedDirectory.path " +
                    " + T(java.io.File).separator + payload.name))"));
    syncProcessor.setAfterRollbackExpression(parser.parseExpression(
            "payload.renameTo(new java.io.File(@inboundFailedDirectory.path " +
                    " + T(java.io.File).separator + payload.name))"));
    return new DefaultTransactionSynchronizationFactory(syncProcessor);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`T(java.nio.file.Files).move(<oldPath>, <newPath>)`

You can use `T(java.io.File).toPath()` to convert a `File` to a `Path`.

Comment: Thank you! I've used it like this: `Expression expression =parser.parseExpression("T(java.nio.file.Files).move(payload.toPath(), "
      + "T(java.nio.file.Path).of(@inboundProcessedDirectory.path, payload.name))");
    syncProcessor.setAfterCommitExpression(expression);
`